# Why would OutOfMemoryException be thrown while using PLINQ Take()?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, .net-4.5, plinq

After I upgraded to DotNet 4.5, a query started giving me OutOfMemoryExceptions.

The (distilled) query is:

```
var tests = new int[]{}
    .AsParallel()
    .GroupBy(_ => _)
    .Take(int.MaxValue)
    .ToArray();
```

I'm posting this for anyone with the same problem. I'll answer below.

Comment: Are you running in 32bit or 64bits?

Comment: I was using this kind of code inside a function that received a parameter with the number of elements to be returned. Passing int.MaxValue (there was an overload which did just that) essentially meant 'take everything'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be a change in the framework.

The Take() operator is implemented in the TakeOrSkipQueryOperator internal class. There is one branch in the code that goes through a WrapHelper() function that creates a FixedMapHeap instance which in turn creates an array of Key elements of the  size passed originally to Take() (which would be an array of 8Gb in the given example).

Comment: @Steven Set a `Take` value for which you have enough memory to store that many results.  (Or get more memory.)

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable optimisation much of the time - should allow for better parallelisation in a lot of cases since different threads can write to different parts of that heap without risk of interfering with each other. The down-side in this case is clear though.

Comment: you should just remove the `Take` from the query when you want all elements.